# Calling bash script from bash script

Tags: bash

I have made two programms and I'm trying to call the one from the other but this is appearing on my screen:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘PerShip/.csv’: No such file or directory
cp: target ‘tmpship.csv’ is not a directory
```

I don't know what to do. Here are the programms. Could somebody help me please?

```
#!/bin/bash
shipname=$1
imo=$(grep "$shipname" shipsNAME-IMO.txt | cut -d "," -f 2)
cp PerShip/$imo'.csv' tmpship.csv
dist=$(octave -q ShipDistance.m 2>/dev/null)
grep "$shipname" shipsNAME-IMO.txt | cut -d "," -f 2 > IMO.txt
idnumber=$(cut -b 4-10 IMO.txt)
echo $idnumber,$dist
```

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f shipsdist.csv
for ship in $(cat shipsNAME-IMO.txt | cut -d "," -f 1)
do
    ./FindShipDistance "$ship" >> shipsdist.csv
done
cat shipsdist.csv | sort | head -n 1
```

Comment: I assume variable `imo` is empty.

Comment: But I can run the first programm without having any problems

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: You are calling the first script from the second script just fine. The second script is not, in general, iterating over your file correctly. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including minimal code, example input (`shipsNAME-IMO.txt` is missing), and expected output. You can [edit].

Comment: What is the value of `$shipname`, and what does `shipsNAME-IMO.txt` look like?

Comment: `grep ... | cut ...` can virtually always be replaced with a single `awk` command.

Comment: If the first program works correctly when you run it directly but not when the second program runs it, then among the likely possibilities is that the second program is running the first *wrongly*.  It seems likely that that takes the form of the second running the first with a bad command-line argument.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that when a ship has a big name, for example "TRITON SEAHAWK" the program reads "TRITON". Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: $shipname is string and shipsNAME-IMO.txt looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

The code and error messages presented suggest that the second script is calling the first with an empty command-line argument.  That would certainly happen if input file `shipsNAME-IMO.txt` contained any empty lines or otherwise any lines with an empty first field.  An empty line at the beginning or end would do it.

I suggest

1. using the `read` command to read the data, and manipulating `IFS` to parse out comma-delimited fields
2. validating your inputs and other data early and often
3. making your scripts behave more pleasantly in the event of predictable failures
4. More generally, using internal Bash features instead of external programs where the former are reasonably natural.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Validate one command-line argument
[[ -n "$1" ]] || { echo empty ship name 1>&2; exit 1; }

# Read and validate an IMO corresponding to the argument
IFS=, read -r dummy imo tail < <(grep -F -- "$1" shipsNAME-IMO.txt)
[[ -f PerShip/"${imo}.csv" ]] || { echo no data for "'$imo'" 1>&2; exit 1; }

# Perform the distance calculation and output the result
cp PerShip/"${imo}.csv" tmpship.csv
dist=$(octave -q ShipDistance.m 2>/dev/null) ||
  { echo "failed to compute ship distance for '${imo}'" 2>&1; exit 1; }
echo "${imo:3:7},${dist}"
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash

# Note: the original shipsdist.csv will be clobbered

while IFS=, read -r ship tail; do
  # Ignore any empty ship name, however it might arise
  [[ -n "$ship" ]] && ./FindShipDistance "$ship"
done < shipsNAME-IMO.txt |
  tee shipsdist.csv |
  sort |
  head -n 1
```

Note that making the `while` loop in the second script part of a pipeline will cause it to run in a subshell.  That is sometimes a gotcha, but it won't cause any problem in this case.